Algorithm for calculating overlaps in an array
I am trying to build a calendar-like app, where different time-blocks indicate what you have planned for the day. If you have multiple things planned that operate into/through eachothers time-ranges, they are counted as overlapping and need to be adjusted so that they aren't overlapping anymore.
Let's say the app has the following overlaps: 0: [0, 1, 2],  1: [0, 1], and 2: [0, 2]. Each number represents a different time-block, and the array is the timeblocks it's overlapping with. In this case, 0 should be rendered with width 50% and left 0%, and then 1 and 2 with width 50% and left 50%. Currently im calculting the insert (left) through (index/overlaps.length) * 100 + "%" which is working great. My current implementation for calculating the width is (1/overlaps.length) * 100 + "%", but this unsurprisingly gives me 33% width for 0, and 50% for 1 and 2, which isn't ideal, as it leaves a little gap between 0 and 1 and 2...

Why must you rely on left to position the blocks correctly when you can let the browser place them correctly?

Realistically all you have to do is set the width.

@mochaccino the modules have to be positioned absolutely as their top-property depends on the start of the time-block, and thus they need the left property. Even if i found a work-around for that, that doesn't solve the problem of calculating the width...

Can you add inputs and expected outputs in your question?

Please be more specific on how the example 0: [0, 1, 2], 1: [0, 1], and 2: [0, 2] should be understood.
